# How should i load external files(i.e. js,css,html) in meteor project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

I am trying to learn meteor and i would like to add js,css and html pages from outside. 
[I have tried to use this package but its not working it seems.](https://github.com/davidd8/meteor-external-file-loader) I tried to add the html file which is stored in different location with following code

```
Template.hello.helpers({
    var row='';
    page(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'Desktop/test.html',
            success:function(html){
                row=html;
            }
        });
        return row;
    }
});
```

It gives unexpected token error.If i remove var row,success and return statement,my app runs with out adding the external page. I have also tried to add JS File with $.getScript(); but it seems its not working for me.If any one can help me,It would be very helpful.

Comment: Why are you trying to load an external html file? Typically you want to organize your html files in templates inside the `client` directory of your project.

Comment: Hi @David, Thanks for your response. I would like to use all these files to be used as external loadable library. Can you suggest me some better way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your intending to do with this external html, but your helper is not properly formatted. Your `row` variable is throwing an error because it is not inside of your function. You can not declare a variable directly inside of an object. Also, your AJAX call is asynchronous, so row will still be defined as `''` when it is returned.

I think you need to look into how templating html works in meteor. You should be placing your row html into its own template, and then including it into the hello template using Spacebars like this:

Hello file:

```
<template name='hello'>
  <h1>Hello and welcome!</h1>
  {{> row }}
</template>
```

Row file:

```
<template name='row'>
  <div class='row'>This is a row.</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Yes, In this way it will work fine, but how external files can be loaded in the app?

Answer (score 0):

OK,I'll try to answer the actual question you asked: How to include an external html file in a template?

Two alternatives:

1. If "external" file is inside your Meteor project, make it a template too: Wrap it with `<template name="xxx"> ... </template>` and then insert it simply by going `{{> xxx}}`.
2. If the file is somewhere else, and really needs to be included via a http call, you put a placeholder element `<div id="fileGoesHere"></div>` where you want it to go, and then in your helper you do:

(See http://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html)

```
function insertExternalFile() {
    HTTP.get( 'http://someurl', ( error, result ) => {
        if( error ) {
           console.log( error );
           return;
        }
        $('#fileGoesHere').html( result );
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @JesperWe , Thanks for your solution. I tried to load a html page which i have created and saved on a particular folder it's not loading. My app is running without any error or warning in browser console log. So is there any other way around to get that page in my app.

Comment: So I have added a check for errors in the code in my answer.

Comment: You should also check in the debugger that the function is actually called. Set a breakpoint at the HTTP.get() call.